# "Missing/Invalid access key" from ACRCloud api

Tags: api

Just getting started with the API at ACRCloud.com.

When testing the example source (only modifying access key and secret from [console.acrcloud.com](https://console.acrcloud.com/account/keys) and the path to the `wav file` to upload),

> I receive the error "Missing/Invalid access key."

Is the problem with the sample source or my access key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying ACRCloud API.

The key and secret you were using is for RESTful API, you will need to find the key and secret of the project for sending requests.

What is more, ACRCloud also provides web api code examples for java, C#, php, python, javascript, ruby and more examples are coming soon~

For the examples, please see here: https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example